# call a class from fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I cannot call outsider class from Fragment, don't why. And show me these message.

**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method selectItem(String, String, String) from the type MainActivity**

here is my coding. I want to call "selectItem" class from ContentFragment. That's problem that I cannot call this class.

```
private void selectItem(String title, String gender, String getStats) {     
    Fragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ContentFragment.JOBTITLE, title);
    args.putString(ContentFragment.JOBGENDER, gender);
    args.putString(ContentFragment.JOBSTATUS, getStats);
    fragment.setArguments(args);        

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

}

public static class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    public ContentFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
        btnPopMsg = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPopMsg);
        btnPopMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                >>>selectItem("", "", "ALL");<<<
            }
        });            
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).selectItem("", "", "ALL");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant call a `static method` in an non-static method. If you want to call the function  in your `onClick`, add the block of code:

```
if(getActivity() instanceof MainActivity){
      ((MainActivity)getActivity()).selectItem("", "", "ALL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must either set a reference to whatever-wrapper-class-is instance after creating a `ContentFragment` instance, and then call the method of the reference. Or you may remove `static` modifier from `ContentFragment` definition if it fits your design. That happens because nested static class' instance may exist without a wrtapper object of wrapper class, thus in the nested class there is no reference to the wrapper class and it can's call wrapper class' methods.